# In Symfony how can you instantely cache the routing.yml?

Tags: caching, routes, symfony1, yaml

I have a file located at [application]/config/routing.yml, when I change something in there, the changes aren't active. This probably has to do with the cache as when I go into that directory [cache]/[application]/prod/config the currently active file can be seen config_routing.yml.php.

The lifetime of the cache is generally 86400 seconds, is there a way that I can immediately view/activate the changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the dev environment instead of the prod environment. You can access the dev environment by going to your index_dev.php file instead of the index.php file:

http://localhost/index_dev.php

The dev environment by passes the cache so you can see your changes immediately. You can also run a clear cache command after each change to see your changes in the prod environment:

```
symfony cc
```

Answer (score 0):

*Always* clear the cache after making a change to a YAML file in symfony, whether you are operating in the dev or prod environment. The dev environment generates the cache for each *web* request, but not for CLI requests. Therefore it's a good habit to always manually run `symfony cc` after a YAML change.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache after changes to any config files: $ symfony cc